# I want setinterval auto refresh only part of script PHP Javascript Ajax

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, setinterval

I have this script that's fetching data from db with my added friends(photo,name,last message recived from that user and the online/offline status and is working just fine but i need to setinterval only a part of script such as online/offline status not entire contact bcz i have li.active on it and when refreshes the user that is set active is dissapear on setinterval, and i want only the online status to refreshed. Here is what i have trying to achive.
[See picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4o0NJ.jpg)

```js
function UpdateUsersList() {
  var to_user_id = $('.contact').attr('id');

  $.ajax({
    url: "pagini/chat/chat_action.php",
    method: "POST",
    data: {
      to_user_id: to_user_id,
      action: 'update_users_list'
    },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(response) {
      var obj = response.status; //<-Online/Offline data
      setInterval(function() {
        if (obj == 0) {
          $(".stslist > span").removeClass().addClass('avt avatar-status-offline');
        } else if (obj == 1) {
          $(".stslist > span").removeClass().addClass('avt avatar-status-online');
        } else if (obj == 2) {
          $(".stslist > span").removeClass().addClass('avt avatar-status-busy');
        } else if (obj == 3) {
          $(".stslist > span").removeClass().addClass('avt avatar-status-away');
        }
      }, 5000);
      $('#userslist').html(response.userslist); //<-This Is the friend box
    }
  });
}
```

PHP Action Code:

```
if($_POST['action'] == 'update_users_list') {
    $userslist = $chat->getUsersList();
 }
```

PHP Userlist Code:

```
 public function getUsersList() {
  $sqlQuery = "SELECT u.* FROM mls_users u INNER JOIN myfriends f ON f.myid = u.id WHERE f.myfriends = ".$_SESSION['user']." AND status = 1;";
    $userChat = $this->getData($sqlQuery);

    $userslist = '';
    $activeUser = '';
    $status = '';

    foreach($userChat as $usrs){

     if($usrs['id'] == $usrs['current_session']) {
           $activeUser = "active";
      }
        if ($usrs['statusonline'] == 0) {
        $status = 'avatar-status-offline';
      } else if ($usrs['statusonline'] == 1) {
        $status = 'avatar-status-online';
      } else if ($usrs['statusonline'] == 2) {
        $status = 'avatar-status-busy';
      }
      else if  ($usrs['statusonline'] == 3) {
        $status = 'avatar-status-away';
      }

     $userslist .= '<li id="'.$usrs['id'].'" status="'.$usrs['statusonline'].'" class="contact '.$activeUser.'" data-touserid="'.$usrs['id'].'" data-tousername="'.$usrs['username'].'">';
     $userslist .= '<div class="pr-1">';
     $userslist .= '<div id="'.$usrs['id'].'" class="stslist avatar m-0 avatar-md">';
     $userslist .= '<img src="'.$usrs['photo'].'" class="media-object rounded-circle" alt="" height="42" width="42" />';
     $userslist .= '<span class="avt '.$status.'"></span>';
     $userslist .= '</div>';
     $userslist .= '</div>';
     $userslist .= '<div class="user-chat-info">';
     $userslist .= '<div class="contact-info">';
     $userslist .= '<h5 class="mb-0 name">'.$usrs['numele'].' '.$usrs['prenumele'].'</h5>';
     $userslist .= '<p class="truncate">'.$this->getLastMessage($usrs['id'], $_SESSION['user']).'</p>';
     $userslist .= '</div>';
     $userslist .= '<div class="contact-meta">';
     $userslist .= '<span class="float-right mb-25">4:14 PM</span>';
     $userslist .= '</div>';
     $userslist .= '</div>';
     $userslist .= '</li>'; 
 }      
    $userslist .= '';

    $data = array(
        "userslist" => $userslist,
        "status"    => $status  
     );
     echo json_encode($data);    
}
```

Comment: Given that the value of `obj` never changes, the interval seems entirely pointless. Also note that if you're building a chat system you should be using Websockets (or similar), not AJAX polling.

Comment: The weksockets idea is really good but i don't know how to implement what i have into websokets, some help is apreciated